# How to delete rows from dataframe?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have dataframe df

```
   df.show()
   id|data|somedata
   1 |k   |v
   2 |s   |d
   3 |f   |k
   .
   .
   .
```

I tried to delete rows from df that id exist in lisst=List(4,9,200) so I used drop like this

```
   val df1=df.drop(col("id").isin(lisst:_*))
```

but does'nt work also I tried

```
   val df1=df.filter(col("id").isin(lisst:_*).drop("id"))
```

but df1 have same rows in df

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply using `filter` or `where` with the condition should work; no `drop` is needed if you don't plan to delete columns:

```
df.filter(!col("id").isin(lisst:_*))
```

or:

```
df.where(!col("id").isin(lisst:_*))
```